# read and parsing the head of the mail file

Tags: php

i have a mail file

i want read/parse the head of the mail file ( head only )

i want read to this line ( Content-Type: ) this is the end of the head

here is an example for the file content

```
Received: from [41.43.66.49] by web121206.mail.ne1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Thu, 15 Mar 2012 03:01:18 PDT
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.117.340979
References: <20120315074428.615964901A4@sat51-alie.secureinternetnews.net>
Message-ID: <1331805678.39182.YahooMailNeo@web121206.mail.ne1.yahoo.com>
Date: Thu, 15 Mar 2012 03:01:18 -0700 (PDT)
From: Black Dream <more_ache@ymail.com>
Reply-To: Black Dream <more_ache@ymail.com>
Subject: Need help installing your certificate?
To: "admin@emiddy-hosting.com" <admin@emiddy-hosting.com>
In-Reply-To: <20120315074428.615964901A4@sat51-alie.secureinternetnews.net>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="1735753853-309369511-1331805678=:39182"

--1735753853-309369511-1331805678=:39182
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="1735753853-307665870-1331805678=:39182"

--1735753853-307665870-1331805678=:39182
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=0A=0A=0A----- Forwarded Message -----=0AComodo Group, Inc. <e-mail= .....
.... hello hello hello ... the message body here
```

and here is the code that i working on

```
$the_mail_data = array ();
$handle = fopen('mail.txt', 'r');
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $break = explode ( ':' , $buffer );
        $the_mail_data[$break[0]] = $break[1];
        if ( $break[0] == 'Content-Type' )
        break;
}
fclose($handle);
    //Now i've the data in this array $the_mail_data();
    //print_r ( $the_mail_data );
    //echo $the_mail_data['subject'];
```

The code is working so fine, but i need something faster!

is any one have a faster function or faster code?

i am trying now ( file_get_contents ) it's seems faster, but it read all the file, i can't read a part of file

Answer (score 0):

You might get your fastest results using sed from the shell to split the file in two parts based on the Content-Type string and then get the results back from the system command:

```
$head = system("sed '1,/^Content-Type$/!d' < mail.txt");
```

You'll likely need a full path to your mail.txt file. Try that out and compare the speed.

Comment: thank you, but your command has been read all the message file, not just part!!

Comment: file_get_contents:Page generated in 0.0002 seconds. 

Sed Command:Page generated in 0.0054 seconds. 

Are you kidding??

Comment: The command should read the entire file and return the first half as output. I wasn't sure if it would be faster or not. Apparently not.